# Query regarding K8S Infrastructure

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have created a k8s cluster and network, using 1 master and 2 nodes, the deployment happens correctly having one pod on each node

From my observation i would like to know, when we deploy the nginx pods (using deployment say replicas = 2) it deploy as a container of node1 or node2. but the nginx service actually runs on the server itself **not** inside the container as i see the service running on node1 and node2 currently?

```
[root@node1 ~]# ps -ef|grep nginx
root     13512 13494  0 10:57 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
101      13531 13512  0 10:57 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
root     17310 16644  0 11:14 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
[root@node1 ~]#
```

Is it a right setup, I have on my machine? that nginx service which is deployed to node1 and node2 from master machine is running on the node servers, though it is created as a part of pod deployment, or should it be running inside the container only?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking at the nginx process running in the container. Look at the parent process of that nginx, it should be the container-shim, or something like that. When you run a process in a container, it runs as one of the processes of the machine, as a child of the container process, with limited access to the parent machine resources.

Comment: the logs which i have posted in my very first post, are from the worker node (node1). So do you mean to say, the services which i have given as a log are suppose to be running on the worker nodes (as they are now) and its child processes should be inside the container server (in this case nginx).

Comment: also, could you please explain a bit about how container-shim works, and what is it significance.

Comment: Search for container-shim, you can find many articles describing how components work together. One is here: http://alexander.holbreich.org/docker-components-explained/ . I do not understand your first question. All processes (nginx, container-shim) are runing on the worker node. The container-shim is simply the parent process of nginx. A process running in a container is still a process of the host machine whose access to resources are controlled by the container.